# Execute a void in variable with parameters

Tags: c#, action, void

I look around the internet and find thing called Action that can execute void methods, if those voids are stores in variables.

```
void push(Action <string> action, string methodURL) {
if (methodURL != "123")
action(methodURL);
}
```

In this case, `action` is a method to execute and `methodURL` is it's future argument.

So, I expected to use this code something like that :

```
push(GetGroups(curTarget), GroupsXML);
```

GroupsXML is a string and GetGroups is a void with a string argument

and Visual Studio is showing me an error :

> 1.)Converting "void" to "action"
>
> 2.)Too much arguments

Comment: What is the error you see?

Comment: Show the code where you call `push`, then we'll have a better idea what you're trying to do. You can't call an `Action<string>` with both `GroupsXML` *and* `curTarget` as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need to put stuff in brackets. C# is smart enough to work out and create the action for you.

```
push(GetGroups, GroupsXML);
```

Will dynamically convert it to an action

The code you have posted doesn't make so much sense though, you are only specifying one parameter into the action, yet you have two floating about curTarget and methodURL.

Comment: What is curTarget? I'm not clear what you are expecting this to do.

The action signature you have specified indicates one single parameter into it, which maps onto your function with one parameter, which you later pass GroupsXML into.

Comment: Man, I just got stupid. Your solution is fine. I just change some parts of code and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: I'll mark your solution as "correct" in 4 minutes, SOF doesn't let me do it now.